# Bash script. create .info.file.prt if file.prt exists.

Tags: bash, file, unix

I have three files in a folder called /folder/files/$SET_DATE/ but may have much more depending on the date.

```
Ben.prt
.info.Ben.prt
Jim.prt
John.prt
```

I would like to create a .info.*.prt file for each .prt file in the folder, but if one already exists, I don't want to create two.

A ll-lart would then leave me with the following.

Server ben 10:30 <~> ll-lart

```
.info.Ben.prt
.info.Jim.prt
.info.John.prt
Ben.prt
Jim.prt
John.prt
```

The values in the .info.* foles would be the count of chars in the .prt files.

so I have the following.

```
SET_DATE= cat /tmp/date.txt

FILES="/folder/folder/folder/$DP_DATE/.info.*"
FILESF="/folder/folder/folder/$DP_DATE/"
FILESP="*.prt"

if [ ! -e $FILESF".info."$FILESP ]; then
echo 0 >> $FILESF.info.$FILESP
fi
```

Finding it hard to get my head around this now though.

Any kick in the right direction would be much appreicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in *.prt
do
    [ -f ".info.$file" ] || wc -c < "$file" > ".info.$file"
done
```

For each `.prt` file name not starting with a `.` dot, if the corresponding `.info` file does not exist, create it with the number of characters found in the file.

Comment: actually, this will not work from an outside directory, do you know how i could run this from a different folder to run against files in this folder?

Comment: The simplest way would be to pass the directory name you want to operate in as an argument, and have the script change directory to that location. The first line, just above the `for` loop, could be `cd ${1:-"."} || exit 1`, meaning change to the directory specified by the first argument, or to the current directory. That avoids having to dissect file names separately from pathnames. The other alternative is to take the names of the files to check as command line arguments. Doing that, though requires you to split names into directory (path) and file name. Doable, but fiddlier.